# WEB Api to firebird database over static ip

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, firebird

How should I build connection string (or what else) to connect from my `WEB API` to my `Firebird` database which is located on the computer with static IP address.

I haven't tried anything because I have no idea of how my connection string would look like since I have only worked with local connections which takes only 4 parameters (`path`, `localhost`, `username`, `pass`).

EDIT: I am not connecting to database which is directly onto computer with static ip.

That computer (with static ip) is also connected with local network, and my database is on second computer on that local network.

Comment: if your connection string includes "localhost" then by definition it is TCP/IP network connection, not local connection. Local connections would not have any computer name, because, well, they are local anyway.

Comment: The additional information you provide in your edit makes this "not a Firebird problem", much less a programming problem, but one of configuring your cable modem or network router to forward the port. Check the documentation of your cable modem or network router. This however implies you're trying to connect to the database over the internet, and you shouldn't do that. If you're creating a web API, that web API should be exposed over the internet, the Firebird database should only be accessible over the internal network.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Firebird connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/) documents and examples:

**Standard**

```
User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=SampleDatabase.fdb;DataSource=localhost;
Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;
MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;
```

Use `static ip` in `DataSource` parameter.

Comment: Ok I get that part, but there are 3 computers on that static ip address, how do I target the one that has database on

Comment: Hold on a minute, You've got one static IP address which is assigned on 3 computers? That's not possible. I think you've got an valid static IP address over the Internet. Is there any NAT on your network? I mean for example 2.2.2.4:8181 will NAT to 192.168.2.2 Firebird.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I was thinking something other and forgot it was setup differently. You are right, there is only one computer with static ip but then there is other problem which I will write at edited question